# Automatically initiate an outbound SSH connection on a server when a client connects

Tags: ssh, iptables

How can I automatically initiate an outbound SSH connection on a server when an internal client connects to that server on a specific port, for any given service, from a given IP range? Note that the connection should not start if it is already up.

It does not appear there is a non-scripting way to do this, as if the connection is already up, there would be no way to detect that using the `Match` and `ForceCommand` method to prevent ssh from attempting to reconnect (or needlessly open an entirely new outbound ssh session).

I therefore have thought of a script like (this is just a draft, to illustrate the idea):

```
#######auto_ssh-script.sh

####### iptables rule logging all new incoming, unestablished, never before seen connections

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state NEW -m state !
--state ESTABLISHED -m state ! --state SEEN_REPLY -j LOG --log-prefix CONNECT

#######background script  --> read log and look for a match to string CONNECT 

cat /proc/kmsg | while read LOGGING 
do   
    LOG='echo "$LOGGING" | grep 'CONNECT' '   
    if ["$LOG" = ' ' ]  &  UP= 'echo alxw | grep ssh '
     if [ "UP" = ' '] then 
     fi  

ssh -p 22 <user>@<somewhere-out-there.com
echo "Connected"
done
```

Isn't there a better way? If not, how can I improve this script?

Comment: There is `sshd_config` option `ForceCommand` which should fit your needs if you put this option into appropriate `Match` block.

Comment: @Jakuje - This looks like a good lead, please elaborate if you can....

Comment: It was never explained why the suggested solutions couldn't work in the given scenario. Only that they weren't acceptable. The "trolling", as you put it, is actually people trying to understand WHY the proposed solutions weren't acceptable, quite possibly with a view to making different suggestions.

Comment: Update - @terdon has edited and updated the question to make it more readable and easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you can create something like this in your `sshd_config`:

```
Match User user Address 192.168.100.0/24 LocalPort 22
  ForceCommand ssh some-other-ip
```

You don't need `LocalPort 22`, if you have running service only on normal port. Client IP range is `192.168.100.1` - `192.168.100.254` and username is `user`.

Comment: Okay. I will try this solution and reply back with the results soon.

Comment: And don't forget to restart the `sshd` server after the change.

Comment: Looks like a script will have to be used. Question updated.